# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown menu in panel header positioned wrong

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and trying to add a dropdown menu to the right side of a panel-header. I have the button positioned with a `float:right` but the dropdown menu doesn't render connected to the button anymore. I think the float is breaking the link with the dropdown menu.

I have tried adding `float:right` and removing the `position:absolute` (overwriting to `position:initial`) I can make the dropdown appear next to the button, but it ends up contained within the `panel-header` div which expands the panel header to the menu size.

Is there anything I can do about this?

There's a Bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/4jVDGUJMYg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place the `dropdown` button inside a `btn-group` tag: see [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single)

Working example Snippet.

```css
 .panel-collapsable .panel-heading h4:after {
   font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
   content: "\e114";
   float: right;
   color: white;
   margin-right: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
 .panel-collapsable .collapsed h4:after {
   content: "\e080";
 }
 .panel-heading .btn-group {
   float: right;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">
      <div class="panel panel-primary panel-collapsable panel-chart">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary toggle-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <h4 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sg1" aria-expanded="true"> Panel Box here <span class="label label-danger">Danger</span> </h4>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="sg1" class="panel-body collapse in" aria-expanded="true">Text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text.
          <br>Text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like the more Bootstrap appropriate solution. The btn-group wrapper was definitely what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css styling to the drop-down:

```
.panel-heading .dropdown-menu {
  right: 31px;
  top: 42px;
  left: initial;
}
```

The absolute positioning is with respect to the parent panel, so you just need to adjust the top/right/left/bottom settings to your liking.